# Why `Dem Computer` and not `Der Computer`?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Dem Computer fehlt ein Hub für USB.

Why *Dem Computer* and not *Der Computer*? Because I think `Dem Computer` is subject, so it should takes the nominative `der` article.

Source:
https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=fehlt

Comment: Can we say?:
Der Computer fehlt einem Hub für USB.
@harper

Comment: no, it is still dative and thus "dem Computer fehlt" - the rest "einem Hub für USB" does not make that much sense.

Comment: "Der Computer fehlt einem Hub für USB." you can say that if there is a hub which lacks a computer. Indeed, it sounds like the hub might be sad because of it.

Comment: @user3640028: Please ask follow-up questions separately instead of the comments.

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to elaborate why you expect *Der Computer* here so we can address your confusion.

Comment: Who deleted my comments and why?

Comment: Where's my comment gone? I didn't delete it.

Comment: @harper i guess it was deleted because it was turned into an answer and marked as "no longer needed". This is very common on SE.

Comment: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment

Comment: That is why you have cases in German -> for being able to exchange subject and object. Vice versa English requires a fixed word order because you don't have cases which clearly indicate subject and objects.

Comment: @miep, my comment qualified as a comment and was still deleted :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Notice that in German, the subject that goes with the verb *fehlen* is the thing that is missing/ lacking/ absent/ not present, and the dative object refers to the thing that "feels" or is impaired by the absence. This is opposite to the English verbs *to miss* or *to lack*!

---

Consider the following simple sentence, which contains only the subject and the verb:

> Ein Hub<sub>(subject)</sub> fehlt<sub>(verb)</sub>.

The subject *ein Hub* is the absent thing.

Now let's add the dative object:

> Ein Hub<sub>(subject)</sub> fehlt<sub>(verb)</sub> dem Computer<sub>(object)</sub>.

The dative object [*dem Computer*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Computer) is the thing that is impaired by the absence of the subject.

Finally, let's rearranged the sentence such that it starts with the object:

> Dem Computer<sub>(object)</sub> fehlt<sub>(verb)</sub> ein Hub<sub>(subject)</sub>.

In English, the roles of subject and object are interchanged, which might have cause the confusion:

> The computer<sub>(subject)</sub> lacks<sub>(verb)</sub> a hub<sub>(object)</sub>.

Answer (score 5):

While Björn Friedrich's answer covers *fehlen*, I feel it would be a mistake not to mention that there are a whole group of verbs that behave just like it: *fehlen, schmecken, gefallen, gehören, passen, stehen* (with the meaning "to suit someone") etc.

The meaning these verbs share is hard to put into words, but a starting point would be to say that for these verbs, the dative object usually denotes a person experiencing something and the subject denotes a thing that is responsible for the experience.

One problem that language learners have is the following. In German, the dative object may precede the subject. If case is not visible, for instance when the dative object is a proper noun, it is very easy to mistake the dative object for a subject. (The dative object is marked in italics and the subject in bold in the following examples.)

> *Hans* schmeckt **die Suppe**. (*Hans likes the soup*, not *Hans tastes the soup*.)
>   *Susi* gefällt **dieses Buch von Stephen King**.
>   *Frau Özel* gehört **das Nachbargrundstück**.
>   *Eltern* fehlen manchmal **Informationen**.

When the dative object is singular and the subject is plural (or vice versa), subject-verb agreement makes it obvious what the subject is.

> *Hans* schmecken **die Würstchen**.
>   *Susi* gefallen **alle Bücher von Stephen King**.
>   *Frau Özel* gehören **mehrere Grundstücke**.
>   *Eltern* fehlt manchmal **die Geduld**.

Of course, when case is visible, no misinterpretation is possible.

> *Ihm* schmeckt **der Salat**.
>   *Ihr* gefällt **dieser Film von Steven Spielberg**.
>   *Ihr* gehört **der Nachbargarten**.
>   *Den Eltern* fehlt manchmal **der Elan**.

Answer (score 0):

Because the noun "der Computer" is masculin and this sentence requires a dative.

Answer (score 0):

The subject is "ein Hub", the object is "der Computer". A Dative object is required here, therefore "dem Computer".
Answered by **@harper**