# Wenn das Verb gefallen den Dativ braucht, ist diese Website korrekt?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality, dative, nominative

Ich habe gelernt, dass das Verb "gefallen" den Dativ braucht.
Aber diese [Internetseite](https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/beispiele/gefallen.htm) nutzt das Nominativ-Personalpronomen im Satz:

> Auch Tom gefällst **du** nicht sehr.

Warum? Ist das richtig?
Ich hoffe, diese Frage wurde noch nicht beantwortet.

Comment: Das ist IMO korrekt: **Wem** gefällst du (nicht)?** => **Toni** (Dativ). **du** ist das Subjekt.

Comment: Auch Tom gefällst dir nicht sehr?

Comment: Wenn man's korrigiert: _"Auch Tom gefällst du nicht sehr?"_ ist es immer noch der Dativ-Bezug zu _Tom_.

Comment: Kannst du das auf Englisch sagen?

Comment: Klar, sogar als Antwort. Aber dann wäre es besser Du stellst Deine Frage komplett auf Englisch (wir unterscheiden das hier, und es ist Beides zulässig).

Comment: If English is fine, this answer may help: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/52599/35111

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In diesem Fall ist *Tom* das Dativobjekt:

> Auch **dem** (=Tom) `gefällst du` nicht sehr.

*Du* ist das Subjekt und steht deshalb im Nominativ: *Du gefäll**s**t*.

---

Wenn *Tom* das Subjekt wäre, müsste der Satz lauten:

> Auch `Tom gefällt` **dir** nicht sehr.

Jetzt steht Tom im Nominativ: *Tom (=er) gefällt*.

Answer (score 4):

Unterscheide die beiden Sätze

> 1. Auch Tom **gefällst** du nicht sehr

und

> 2. Auch Tom **gefällt** Dir nicht sehr

Im 1. Fall ist *du* das Subjekt (erkennbar an der 2. Person Singular **Du gefällst**). Tom ist hier das Dativobjekt, allerdings nicht erkennbar, da der Name unverändert bleibt.

Ersetzen wir Tom durch *Er*, so wird dieser Satz

> Auch ihm gefällst du nicht sehr

Das bedeutet in anderen Worten: Tom mag dich nicht.

Im 2. Satz ist Tom das Subjekt (erkennbar an der 3. Person Singuler **Tom gefällt**). Dieser Satz bedeutet: Du magst Tom nicht.